# Dynamically return from Neo4jclient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I know how to dynamically create my `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses, and in my situation it's unfortunately something I've got to do... SO, I have something like (and this is a contrived example):

```
var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Match("(u1:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web)","(u2:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web)","(u3:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web)")
    .Where("u1.User.Id = {u1Param}").WithParam("u1Param", 1)
    .AndWhere("u2.User.Id = {u2Param}").WithParam("u2Param", 2)
    .AndWhere("u3.User.Id = {u3Param}").WithParam("u3Param", 3);
```

The `Match` and `Where` are dynamically generated based on user input, and this generates the correct Cypher.

```
MATCH 
    (u1:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web),  (u2:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web),  (u3:User)-[:LINKED]->(w:Web)
WHERE 
    u1.User.Id = 1
    AND u2.User.Id = 2
    AND u3.User.Id = 3
```

On the server (in Cypher) I can do something like:

```
RETURN u1, u2, u3
```

and I'll get the 3 nodes I'm looking for. My problem is the general way of `Returning` data via the neo4jclient is via an Expression, so, to replicate I would do:

```
query.Return(
    (u1, u2, u3) => 
    { 
        U1 = u1.As<User>(), 
        U2 = u2.As<User>(), 
        U3 = u3.As<User>()
    });
```

I don't know that there will only be '3' responses, there could be many more, or indeed less. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Either as is, or in a totally different way, I'm open to all options.

I'd like to something like:

```
 query.Return<User>("u1", "u2", "u3"); //returning IEnumerable<User>
```

or maybe:

```
 query.Return<User>("u1").AndReturn("u2").AndReturn("u3");
```

I know I can revert for these queries to calling the db directly through `HttpClient` or some such, but I'd rather avoid that if I can. To be honest I'd be happy with parsing them all to `dynamic`, but that's not possible at present (or is it??? :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4jClient doesn't have any good solutions for dynamic return shapes like this.

In this contrived example at least, can you just flatten the nodes into a single list?

```
.Return<IEnumerable<User>>("[u1, u2, u3]")
```

You can easily tell which is which with the `Id` property that you're using in the `WHERE` clause but would also be available in C#.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is a check in the code for `,` which results in an Exception: "The overload you have called takes an identity (for example: foo), but it looks like you've tried to pass in a multiple column statement (for example: foo,bar)"

Comment: However, if I skip over that in the debugger it works as expected, I will put in a pull request with a fix...

Comment: You could have done .Return(() => new { Users = Return.As<IEnumerable<User>>("[u1, u2, u3]") }).Results.SelectMany(r => r.Users) as a clunky workaround. :)